# is there anyway to download directory from webbased svn all at once

Tags: svn, download

i have this link but i am trying to figure out how to download the entire directory and subdirectories at once  ..

http://dennisburton.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PostSamples/ModelBinderPosts/

Comment: lol, just ran across this searching. Glad you liked the post. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `svn export http://dennisburton.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PostSamples/ModelBinderPosts/`

This will not create a working copy, but just download the latest version. Checkout will create a working copy, which is larger on disk. You can use the working copy to commit changes, and update more efficiently. Exporting doesn't allow you to commit or update (you'll need to export the whole thing again when one small changes occurs)

Answer (score 0):

Performing a subversion checkout will download the entire directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

Use some subversion client like [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/about), or use svn support in some IDE like [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org).

As repository URL choose http://dennisburton.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ and simple choose the directory you want to checkout (download)